# Incompatible arguments in c++

Tags: c++, arguments

I am sure this is a pretty basic question, but the following code is generating the error 
"**Error: Argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *" in "main.cpp", Line: 54, Col: 16**"

```
  for(int i = 0; i < 16; i ++){
pc.printf("Value at channel ");
pc.printf(i);
}
```

I think I understand why it is saying this, but what do I do about it?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `pc.printf("%d",i);`

Comment: @George Edwards It means that 1) you should at last read the description of function pc.printf; 2) supply correct arguments for it.

Answer (score 2):

You should provide type specifier

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 16; i ++){
    pc.printf("Value at channel ");
    pc.printf("%d",i);
    }
```

Comment: Or in case c++11 std::string s = std::to_string(1); print( s.c_str() );